# A professional geographer who is a sports enthusiast

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, geography, sports

A professional geographer is also a sports enthusiast. He is a fan of these three sportspersons in particular:

1. Lewis Hamilton
2. Nelson Evora
3. A FIFA World Cup winner with Spain

---

To honour all three of them, he made a cube which looks like this:

[image]

---

**Whose image is on the unseen face of this cube?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that on the bottom we will find...

> Fernando Torres

Why?

> We get three coordinates on the cube, each opposite to one of the pictures.
>  (I used https://ezgif.com/split to read the coordinates without getting a headache...)
>
>  opposite of LH: 37°53'4.22"N 4°46'46,45"W
>  opposite of NE: 41°20'25"N 6°42'58"
>  opposite of our missing person: 29°50'12"N, 129°51'13"E

Hm. Somewhere in Spain, Portugal and Japan. Not sooo helpfull. But wait..

> If we also consider that these coordinates reley to their antipode, let's give that a try. https://www.antipodesmap.com/ will help us.
>
>  **Nelson**:
>  [image: nelson]
>  Bingo?
>
>  **Hamilton**:
>  [image: hamliton]
>  Bingo!

So, for the final step:

> [image: missing one]
>  Hm... one name in that area sounds familiar. But was he in the 2010 squad? - Let's ask https://sportslens.com/news/spain-2010-world-cup-squad/

> He was. :-)

Comment: Brilliant work! Nicely explained as well :-)